# Make multiple menu buttons on a gui

Tags: python, user-interface, menu, tkinter

I am trying to make second menu button next to the one i already made but no matter what code i use, i cannot make a second one. I want to place it next the first button by using .grid() not .place()

heres the code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import ctypes


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
      Frame.__init__(self,master)
      self.grid()
      self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):

    mb = Menubutton (self, text="Sniper Rifle", relief=RAISED)
    mb.menu  =  Menu (mb, tearoff = 0)
    mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu

    self.m40a5Var  = IntVar()
    self.srrVar = IntVar()

    mb.menu.add_checkbutton (label="M40A5", variable=self.m40a5Var)
    mb.menu.add_checkbutton (label="SRR", variable=self.srrVar)
    mb.grid()


root = Tk()
root.title("heeey")
root.geometry("180x100")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using menubuttons rather than creating a proper menubar and associating it with the window?

Comment: Im trying to have a user select certain gun (guns in a game, BF4) and then choose attachments with a button next to it. a menu bar wouldn't be appropriate for the thing im trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  understand the question. You say that no matter what you try you can't create a second button. All you have to do to create another button is... create another button:

```
mb = Menubutton(...)
another_mb = Menubutton(...)
...
mb.grid(row=0, column=0)
another_mb.grid(row=0, column=1)
```